# numpy.ndarray.astype not working in numba.jit

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

Hello fellow programmers!

I am trying to free a two dimensional array from complex numbers in a function decorated with `numba.jit`:

Function without `numba.jit` (works):

```
import numpy as np
import numba

def main():
    KAM = np.array([[ -106.66666667-0.j,    42.66666667+0.j,    42.66666667+0.j,     21.33333333+0.j,     0.        +0.j],
                   [   42.66666667+0.j,   -42.66666667-0.j,     0.        +0.j,      0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j],
                   [   42.66666667+0.j,     0.        +0.j,   -42.66666667-0.j,      0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j],
                   [   21.33333333+0.j,     0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j,  -1088.        -0.j,  1066.66666667+0.j],
                   [    0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j,   1066.66666667+0.j, -1066.66666667-0.j]])

    KAM = KAM.astype(float)
    print(KAM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py:11: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  KAM = KAM.astype(float)
[[ -106.66666667    42.66666667    42.66666667    21.33333333
      0.        ]
 [   42.66666667   -42.66666667     0.             0.
      0.        ]
 [   42.66666667     0.           -42.66666667     0.
      0.        ]
 [   21.33333333     0.             0.         -1088.
   1066.66666667]
 [    0.             0.             0.          1066.66666667
  -1066.66666667]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Function decorated with `numba.jit`:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def main():
    KAM = np.array([[ -106.66666667-0.j,    42.66666667+0.j,    42.66666667+0.j,     21.33333333+0.j,     0.        +0.j],
                   [   42.66666667+0.j,   -42.66666667-0.j,     0.        +0.j,      0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j],
                   [   42.66666667+0.j,     0.        +0.j,   -42.66666667-0.j,      0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j],
                   [   21.33333333+0.j,     0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j,  -1088.        -0.j,  1066.66666667+0.j],
                   [    0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j,     0.        +0.j,   1066.66666667+0.j, -1066.66666667-0.j]])

    KAM = KAM.astype(float)
    print(KAM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.astype for array(complex128, 2d, C)) with parameters (Function(<class 'float'>))
 * parameterized
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.astype for array(complex128, 2d, C))
[2] During: typing of call at C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (12)


File "test2.py", line 12:
def main():
    <source elided>

    KAM = KAM.astype(float)
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This problem seems to not come from the complex values although they are mentioned in the error message. Running the same code without complex values in `KAM` results to the same error:

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def main():
    KAM = np.array([[ -106.66666667,    42.66666667,    42.66666667,     21.33333333,     0.        ],
                   [   42.66666667,   -42.66666667,     0.        ,      0.        ,     0.        ],
                   [   42.66666667,     0.        ,   -42.66666667,      0.        ,     0.        ],
                   [   21.33333333,     0.        ,     0.        ,  -1088.        ,  1066.66666667],
                   [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ,   1066.66666667, -1066.66666667]])

    KAM = KAM.astype(float)
    print(KAM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\python.exe C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 401, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 344, in error_rewrite
    reraise(type(e), e, None)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\core\utils.py", line 80, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of BoundFunction(array.astype for array(float64, 2d, C)) with parameters (Function(<class 'float'>))
 * parameterized
[1] During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction(array.astype for array(float64, 2d, C))
[2] During: typing of call at C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/RL_framework/help_functions/test2.py (18)


File "test2.py", line 18:
def main():
    <source elided>

    KAM = KAM.astype(float)
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `.astype(float)` to convert complex numbers to real ones.

Use `np.real(arr)` to get the real parts and if desired `np.imag(arr)` to get the imaginary parts. If you want the magnitudes of the complex numbers use `np.abs(arr)`. All work with `numba`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and suggestions!

Comment: Hi, I ran into a similar problem, but trying to coerce a float array into a integer one. I tried with `np.array(float_array, dtype=int)` but numba gave me an error. Do you happen to have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Okay nevermind, I figured it out. In case anyone runs into the same problem, for me it worked by using `float_array.astype(np.int_)` (numba version 0.52.0)

Comment: @Álvaro I am not sure what `int_` is but for sure you can use `astype` with type declared in numpy like uint8 int8 int16 int32 etc. you just can't use python types like `int` numba will not recognize witch type to use.